# Pass jQuery dynamic data to GoogleMaps API

Tags: jquery, google-maps, slider

I have a simple jQuery slider which allows the user to slide through a time scale, and an embedded Google Maps (API V3). The code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Slider
    $(function() {
           $( "#slider" ).slider({
                value:0,
                min: 0.00,
                max: 24.00,
                step: 1,
                slide: function( event, ui ) {
                  $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value + " hrs");
                }
           });
           $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) + " hrs" );
    });
</script>
```

Followed by the map:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function init() {
    // pass in json data from django
    var json_data = {{ json_data|safe }};

    // custom settings
    ...

    // initialize map 
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), settings); 

    // create custom markers
    ...

    for (var i = 0; i < json_data.length; i++) {
        ... 
        if ( json_data[i][3] == time) {
        // custom marker logic
        ...
        }; 

    } // end for loop
} // end function         
$(function(){

// initialize map
init();

// get slider value
$("#slider").bind("slide", function(event, ui) {
    var time = ui.value;
});
</script>
```

Hopefully this is clear. I am basically missing the glue between these two. I can get the value of the slider as the cursor is moved (`var time = ui.value`), but how can I pass this dynamic variable `time` to the maps script as the slider is moved?

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got the slightest clue of what you want to achieve, but I can take a guess.

```
for (var i = 0; i < json_data.length; i++) {
    ... 
    if ( json_data[i][3] == time) {
    // custom marker logic
    ...
    }; 
}
```

I believe this is the piece of code that should be called every time the 'slide' event is triggered.

Well, you just need to move this piece of code inside the slide handler (after var time = ui.value;) so it's called every time and you have access to the time variable. The init() function I believe it's called only once, so it's of no use.

Also, I believe you must display a custom set of markers from a larger data set. For that, be sure to iterate through all markers from the larger data set and call setMap(null) so you're hiding all the markers before displaying the suitable ones.

Let me know if this is what you're looking for.